# Cordova (version 10.x) - Ajax POST method not working for Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using latest version of Cordova (v10.x) and Cordova Android (v10.x). Also I am using Framework7 for html/template.

The Ajax "POST" and "GET" is working fine on browser `$ cordova run browser`

But on Android "GET" method is working fine but "POST" method is not working. Sample Ajax type "GET" -

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            "privacy": "yes"
        },
        url: 'https://api_link_here.com',
        success: function(response) {
            //THIS WORKS FINE
        }
});
```

But if it is `type: 'POST'` then it doesn't work, I mean it doesn't run, it doesn't try access the API url. I have tried many solutions/solved answers available on stackoverflow for similar cases but none of them works (actually those answers are for old versions)

In my `config.xml` file, I have this:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<preferance name="android-usesCleartextTraffic" value="true" />
.....
```

And in my AndroidManifes.xml -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.mywebsite.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Almost 3 years ago I build a similar app and it works well. At that time there was an Cordova plugin "Whitelist". But with this new version cordova Whitelist plugin is not supported. Even if I add it manually, it get skipped automatically.

Please suggest. I am exhausted :-(

Comment: "Doesn't work" what is the error ?

Comment: @Eric I can't see any error. Ajax is simply not running. It is not accessing the API URL. In my website (API), I have made a function so that if Ajax access it, it will write to my database. This way I confirm myself whether ajax is sending request or not. Both POST & GET type is working fine on browser but not on Android

Comment: You mean in the network tab, there is no call to your server?

Comment: @Eric yes, no call to the server

Comment: You need to uninstall your whitelist plugin and uninstall android platform and then re-add android platform from CLI, this will fix your problem for sure!

Comment: @stillKonfuzed Recent days Cordova have grown smart enough. I already have tried your solution. Every time I tried to install whitelist plugin, it get skipped for android platform.

Comment: I just asked to remove the whitelist plugin and do not install it again on cordova 10+ android

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall whitelist plugin
2. Remove android platform, then add this code to your `config.xml` :

```
<access origin="*" />
.
.
.
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```